# Custom icon in list

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use a custom icon in my list. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLyz552c/1/). I am trying to follow these [instructions](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/#CustomIcons), but I can't make it work. Also, I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041691/2411320), but it works with older versions of jQuery mobile.

I am trying to do it with this CSS:

```
.ui-icon-myicon:after {
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Dell_Logo.png/1027px-Dell_Logo.png");
}
```

Check the first two elements of the lists. They represent my two best attempts. I want to change the icon of the list in the right, i.e. the arrow pointing to the right.

---

What I want actually, is to list players there and the custom icons will be CF, DMF, AMF, SB, etc..

Comment: The element appears differently to the others. Is that not the desired effect? Please explain the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen, nice top-all-time-answer by the way!

Comment: why thank you :) lol

Comment: @RachelGallen because it is simple and elegant. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesn;t quite fit but getting there http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/z5suac2x/ (I just did the first line)

```css
.ui-icon-myicon:after {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Dell_Logo.png/1027px-Dell_Logo.png");
}
.ui-icon-dell {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Dell_Logo.png/1027px-Dell_Logo.png");
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 99%;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div class="ui-grid-solo" id="slots">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <ol data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li data-role="list-divider">Europe</li>
          <li class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-myicon" data-icon="dell"><a href="#">myicon</a>
          </li>
          <li class="ui-icon-myicon" id="myicon"><a href="#">custom-icon</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Norway</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Germany</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">India</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Thailand</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Zimbabwe</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Uganda</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close call. If I alter the dimensions of the logo to 20x20, the size is right. How to move it a little to the left though, in order to fit perfectly? :/

Comment: hmm, i tried with padding-right:2.5em!important but i think you would have to jig it into the jquery mobile script to make it work properly cos it didn't budge

Comment: Well, I am downloading the script every time as you seen in my fiddle. I will try to work on your answer, if I have something I will report back! (really good attempt, that's why I gave you +1). Maybe you can upvote my question in order to get attention! :)

Comment: background-position:99%; background-size:22px 22px;

Comment: I think we need something like 94 or 95, don't you agree? :) In the fiddle, when I put 94%, it will have problems when the screen resizes. However, in my actual project it works like a charm!

Comment: No cos if you look at the result http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/z5suac2x/embedded/result/ i would even give it a decimal point more

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the background image dimensions:

```
background-size:20px 20px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cLyz552c/2/

Comment: Lowkase, sorry. Maybe you didn't catch up with my edit. What I want to change is the icon on the left, i.e. the arrow pointing to the right! Do you understand?